# What to do with oauth2 access_token

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

After going through multiple steps of OAuth2, what should be done with the access_token once it is received?

```
app.get('/oauth2', function(req, res) {
  var code = req.query.code;

  var url = "https://.../oauth/access_token";
  var options = {
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    form: {
      client_id: '...',
      client_secret: '...',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2',
      code: code,
    },
    json: true
  }

  request(options, function(err, response, body) {

    // I need to save the user in database if she doesn't exist
    // Then redirect, but should I pass the access_token to the redirect?
    res.redirect('/'); // or res.redirect('/?access_token=zzz')
  }

  // Also, should the access_token be encrypted
  // Does it need to be saved in database?
  // Does it go in local storage?

});
```

I will want some of the information that I receive in the reponse and so it needs to be stored in the database. But what specifically do I do with the access_token? Does it get saved to the database? Should it be encrypted? When I redirect, do I add it as a query string? Do I store it in local storage? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

First, your code includes `json: true`, but RFC 6749 [4.1.3. Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) states that parameters should be sent using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Second, the format of a response from a token endpoint is JSON. See [4.1.4. Access Token Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4) for details.

Third, after you get an access token, you should save it for later use. The place to save an access token in is up to you. Datebase, on-memory, and wherever you like. If you want to encrypt an access token when you save it, do it as you like.

Finally, an access token is used to call Web APIs of a resource server. In normal cases, implementations of Web APIs accept an access token in the ways defined in [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750). In the specification, the following three ways are defined.

1. [In Authorization header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1)
2. [As a Form parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2)
3. [As a Query parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.3)